# How does kafka GroupCoordinator play a role in kafka connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

In kafka connect distributed mode, we need to submit kafka connect source and kafka connect sink configuration through REST api. How does Kafka Connect leverage kafka group coordinator to form a consumer group?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka sink connectors form consumer groups using regular consumer API with a `group.id` named `connect-<name>`, using the `name` you've configured in the connector config